# Outputting data from db using jpa

Tags: java, jpa

Hi im trying to print all customers from db using jpa, but the output i get is in the following format : `model.Customer@3d47d922, model.Customer@5f6f2271, model.Customer@6facbae5`

Heres the dao method im using :

```
public List<Customer> getAllCustomers()
    {
        EntityManager em = null;
        List<Customer> resultList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        try
        {
            em = JpaUtil.getFactory().createEntityManager();
            TypedQuery<Customer> query = em.createQuery("select p from Customer p", Customer.class);
            resultList = query.getResultList();

        }
        finally {

            JpaUtil.closeQuietly(em);
        }
        return resultList;
```

Heres servlet where i try to output customers:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    CustomerDAO dao = new CustomerDAO();    

    response.getWriter().println(dao.getAllCustomers());
```

Heres my model class :

```
    @Entity
    public class Customer {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq", sequenceName = "seq1", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "my_seq")
    private Long id;


    private String first_name;


    private String surname;
    private String code;
    public enum Customertype{Private, Corporate};
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Customertype customer_type;


    public Customer() {}


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstname) {
        first_name = firstname;
    }


    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }


    public void setSurname(String surName) {
        surname = surName;
    }


    public Customertype getCustomertype() {
        return customer_type;
    }


    public void setCustomertype(Customertype customerType) {

        this.customer_type = customerType;
    }


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }


    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }



}
```

Comment: Fail to see the relevance of JPA to this. This is basic Java toString, nothing more; try it with ANY object

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the [toString() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in your customer class. The toString() method is called whenever you try to print an object using println().

The default behavior of toString() in the Object class is to print the name of the class , an @ sign and a hascode for the object. That is what you are seeing.

For example

```
public String toString(){
    return this.getFirstName();
}
```

Comment: So i need to overide each row separately?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `toString` method in your class because it is going to give you clear information about the object in readable format that you can understand.

The merit about overriding `toString`:

> Help the programmer for **logging** and **debugging of Java program**
>
> Since **toString** is defined in **java.lang.Object** and does not give valuable information, so it is
>      good practice to override it for subclasses.

Comment: So i need to overide each row in my entity class separately?

Comment: @JuuriPeeter you have to override your toString method in Customre class.

Comment: No. Look at your Customer class. Also look at the documentation that I linked to. You need to add a method named toString that returns a String in the Customer class. This String will be whatever you think a customer description will look like. Entirely up to you. Whatever you return from toString will be printed by your program.